# Symfony bundle to create wiki pages

Tags: symfony, wiki, easyadmin, bundles

I'm working on a project with `Symfony` 5.4 and EasyAdmin 4, and I've been asked to find a bundle to create a new section in my project for managing documentation on clients, projects, login data, etc. Its structure should be similar to BookStack.

Do you know of any Symfony bundles that can do this? I've only found some on GitHub, but they are very old projects that haven't been updated. Thanks to anyone who can help me!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are looking for.  Do you just want to add a WYSIWYG editor to add documentation to your already available entities?  What features of BookStack are you looking for? And which bundles do you already have explored that may or may not cover the features you are searching for?